# delete row from a database table in symfony

Tags: symfony

i want to delete the selected row from an html table that displays the orders list . this is the table code :

```
 {% for reservation in ListeDesReservations %}
            <tr>
    //columns ... //
                <td class="text-center text-lg text-medium">{{ reservation.seat}}</td>
                <td class="text-center text-lg text-medium">{{ reservation.getEvent().getPrix()}}</td>
              {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
                {% set url = absolute_url(asset('')) ~ 'app_dev.php/supprimerReservation/' ~ reservation.id  %}
              {% else %}
                {% set url = "OTHER_URL" %}
              {% endif %}
                <td class="text-center"><a  href="{{url}}" ></a></td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

this my delete method in the controller   :

```
    public function SupprimerReservationAction($idReservation){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $entite = $em->getRepository('techeventBundle:reservation')->find($idReservation);
        $em->remove($entite);
        $em->persist($entite);
        $em->flush();
        //Affichage
        $iduser = $this->getUser()->getId();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('affichage', ['iduser' => $iduser]);
        //Affichage
    }
```

this is my routing file :

```
affichage:
    path:     /afficherPanier/{iduser}
    defaults: { _controller: reservationBundle:Default:afficherPanier }

supprimerReservation:
    path:     /supprimerReservation/{idReservation}
    defaults: { _controller: reservationBundle:Default:SupprimerReservation }
```

the problem is when i click on the remove link it redirects me to the same link 
(app_dev.php/afficherPanier/2)  while it's supposed to redirect me to the delete route (app_dev.php/supprimerReservation/27)

Comment: Why doing : `{% set url = absolute_url(asset('')) ~ 'app_dev.php/supprimerReservation/' ~ reservation.id  %}` (that might not work) when you can simply write : `{% set url = path('supprimerReservation', {'idReservation': reservation.id })  %}`

Comment: @Cid yeah i am wrong , it's supposed to be not commented ! i copied the wrong code

Comment: @Cid when i remove ( redirect to url ) it redirects me to the right url /supprimer/27 ! i think the problem comes from it !  that's why i have commented it

Comment: This is a normal behaviour. *"it redirects me to the same link"* -> `return $this->redirectToRoute('affichage' ... );` You are doing the redirection in the action. Was the deletion done succesfully ?

Comment: You should check the profiler to notice what's going, what have been done, what are the redirections and so on

Comment: no the deletion action is not done even when i am redirected successfully to the delete route

Comment: `$em->remove($entite);` and then `$em->persist($entite);`. You remove and save it back, that's why your entity isn't deleted. Remove that `persist`

Comment: @Cid it's working thanks but i had to remove the redirect to route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller action you are doing :

```
$em->remove($entite);
$em->persist($entite);
```

You are removing then saving the entity. Remove the `$em->persist($entite);` line.

---

Your redirection is a normal behaviour since you are requesting it in your controller action `return $this->redirectToRoute('affichage', ['iduser' => $iduser]);`

---

Note : This is not how is supposed to be build a path `{% set url = absolute_url(asset('')) ~ 'app_dev.php/supprimerReservation/' ~ reservation.id  %}`

Twig has a method named `path` that allows you to build URLs based on the route name

```
{% set url = path('supprimerReservation', {'idReservation': reservation.id }) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to work with annotations for routes. Makes things easier.

What you're doing is far from being the proper way to go about it.

Your delete fonction will not work properly either...
You're deleting with `$em->remove($entite)`, then creating with `$em->persist($entite)`.
Doing this won't ends well for sure.

Your twig is a mess...
We don't create URLs the way you did. There is the [twig extension `path`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/twig_reference.html#path) to do it.

I would suggest to start reading about Symfony :

[Creating a Simple Form](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/forms.html)

[Persist/Fetch/Update/Delete an Object in the Database](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database)

[Controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller.html)

The links above are for Symfony 3.4.
Make sure to change the version with the dropdown select on the page to your corresponding Symfony version if you're not using Symfony 3.4

Comment: i agree i am still learning , i will try to improve my code thanks for you answer .